# Unable to export database using smuggler

Tags: .net, ravendb, ravendb4, ravendb-http, ravendb5

I am trying to clone a database by providing source db name and target db name(both are created), on the same server(same documentstore url). But it doesn't do anything without throwing any exception. Below is the code:

```
Console.WriteLine("start");
var exportOperation =  await store
    .Smuggler
    .ForDatabase(name)
    .ExportAsync(
        new DatabaseSmugglerExportOptions(),
        store.Smuggler.ForDatabase(target));
await exportOperation.WaitForCompletionAsync();
Console.WriteLine("ends");
```

It's a console application, the program is halted while executing ExportAsync function. I am using latest version of ravendb and ravendb.client, and I've .Net 6.

Expected result would be to copy all the content from source db to target db.

Comment: What is the exact exception you are getting ?

Comment: @Danielle Not getting any exception.
Got this response from RavenDB support but don't know exactly what the meant:

"That is not how it works, you cannot do an import / export directly between nodes like that.
You have to get the export file and then import it to the other side.

If you want the servers to directly move the data between one another, either use external replication or RavenDB ETL (if interested in just specific collections) for that. Note that in both cases, that will move the data to the other side and keep updating that."

Comment: 1. As I understand, you should **export** to a `*.ravendbdump` file
and then **import** to the other database.
2. Q: What happens when you **run with explicit options** inside ? **e.g.**:`new DatabaseSmugglerExportOptions  {  OperateOnTypes = DatabaseItemType.Indexes                             | DatabaseItemType.Documents }`